# django-cms simple plugin for news and categories

Tags: django, django-cms

Which plugin for news with categories are the best? Simple news and articles with simple categories.

Example:

I would like to create a page and in this page I would like take a list of news and details of the news and also in the one column have the navigation and also breadcrumbs. I would like to use plugin with this standard navigation: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/getting_started/navigation.html

Answer (score 2):

[**`cmsplugin_news`**](https://bitbucket.org/MrOxiMoron/cmsplugin-news/src/03ba1b86624b/cmsplugin_news) or [**`cmsplugin_advancednews`**](https://bitbucket.org/chernysh/cmsplugin-advancednews/) are two plugins for django-cms that deal with news. [**`Arkestra`**](https://github.com/evildmp/Arkestra) is a content publishing layer built on top of django-cms. [**`Armstrong`**](http://armstrongcms.org/) is a django alternative to django-cms and has news publishing in mind so it might be appropriate if you need something more advanced. If none of these fit the bill, it's quite easy to write your own application and then [creating a django-cms plugin](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.1.3/extending_cms/custom_plugins.html)

Comment: have you tried any of the suggestions? They will more then likely work fine with 1.3

Comment: Yes, i have tried cmsplugin_news and cmsplugin_advancednews and the problem is that with django 1.3 i have this error (admin panel):  

get_text_enabled_plugins() takes exactly 3 non-keyword arguments (2 given)

Comment: Then it looks like you will have to either monkey patch it, write your own or use an alternative like arkestra or armstrong

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is probably too late to help you, but might be useful for future reference - your needs look like they'd be met with [Arkestra](http://arkestra-project.org)

Comment: Just a word of warning: It seems you are personally involved in this projects. Please have a look at the FAQ entry on promotion for some helpful pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion